# Docker PHP-FPM Alpine with SQLSRV Driver Error

Tags: php, docker, sqlsrv

I am getting this error when I try to connect to the sqlserver db:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension 
requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC 
Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This 
extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the 
ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) )
```

My Dockerfile below:

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-tools as mssql
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

COPY --from=mssql /opt/microsoft/ /opt/microsoft/
COPY --from=mssql /opt/mssql-tools/ /opt/mssql-tools/
COPY --from=mssql /usr/lib/libmsodbcsql-13.so /usr/lib/libmsodbcsql-13.so

RUN apk update \
&& apk add  --no-cache git mysql-client curl libmcrypt libmcrypt-dev openssh-client icu-dev 
unixodbc-dev \
libxml2-dev freetype-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev g++ make autoconf \
&& docker-php-source extract \
&& pecl install xdebug redis \
&& docker-php-ext-enable xdebug redis \
&& docker-php-source delete \
&& docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql soap intl zip \
&& pecl install \
    sqlsrv \
    pdo_sqlsrv \
&& docker-php-ext-enable --ini-name 30-sqlsrv.ini sqlsrv \
&& docker-php-ext-enable --ini-name 35-pdo_sqlsrv.ini pdo_sqlsrv \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=off" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_port=10000" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
#&& curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
&& rm -rf /tmp/*

CMD ["php-fpm", "-F"]

WORKDIR /var/www/cssp

EXPOSE 9000
```

It seems there is a problem with the installation of the driver
Has anyone tried this before? Please share. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Try with below DockerFile

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-tools as mssql
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

COPY --from=mssql /opt/microsoft/ /opt/microsoft/
COPY --from=mssql /opt/mssql-tools/ /opt/mssql-tools/
COPY --from=mssql /usr/lib/libmsodbcsql-13.so /usr/lib/libmsodbcsql-13.so

# Install language pack
ENV MUSL_LOCALE_DEPS cmake make musl-dev gcc gettext-dev libintl
ENV MUSL_LOCPATH /usr/share/i18n/locales/musl

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    $MUSL_LOCALE_DEPS \
    && wget https://gitlab.com/rilian-la-te/musl-locales/-/archive/master/musl-locales-master.zip \
    && unzip musl-locales-master.zip \
      && cd musl-locales-master \
      && cmake -DLOCALE_PROFILE=OFF -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr . && make && make install \
      && cd .. && rm -r musl-locales-master

# --- not show here---

# mssql odbc for dabase connection
RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/msodbcsql17_17.5.2.1-1_amd64.apk
RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/mssql-tools_17.5.2.1-1_amd64.apk
RUN apk add --allow-untrusted msodbcsql17_17.5.2.1-1_amd64.apk
RUN apk add --allow-untrusted mssql-tools_17.5.2.1-1_amd64.apk

RUN set -xe \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .persistent-deps freetds unixodbc \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps $PHPIZE_DEPS unixodbc-dev freetds-dev \
    && docker-php-source extract \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_dblib \
    && pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv \
    && docker-php-ext-enable --ini-name 30-sqlsrv.ini sqlsrv \
    && docker-php-ext-enable --ini-name 35-pdo_sqlsrv.ini pdo_sqlsrv \
    && docker-php-source delete \
    && apk del .build-deps
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're stuck with php 7.1 like I do now, here is the updated Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql-tools as mssql
FROM FROM php:7.1-fpm-alpine

ENV MUSL_LOCALE_DEPS cmake make musl-dev gcc gettext-dev libintl
ENV MUSL_LOCPATH /usr/share/i18n/locales/musl

COPY --from=mssql /opt/microsoft/ /opt/microsoft/
COPY --from=mssql /opt/mssql-tools/ /opt/mssql-tools/
COPY --from=mssql /usr/lib/libmsodbcsql-13.so /usr/lib/libmsodbcsql-13.so

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    $MUSL_LOCALE_DEPS \
    && wget https://gitlab.com/rilian-la-te/musl-locales/-/archive/master/musl-locales-master.zip \
    && unzip musl-locales-master.zip \
      && cd musl-locales-master \
      && cmake -DLOCALE_PROFILE=OFF -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr . && make && make install \
      && cd .. && rm -r musl-locales-master

# mssql odbc for dabase connection
RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/msodbcsql17_17.5.2.1-1_amd64.apk
RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/mssql-tools_17.5.2.1-1_amd64.apk
RUN apk add --allow-untrusted msodbcsql17_17.5.2.1-1_amd64.apk
RUN apk add --allow-untrusted mssql-tools_17.5.2.1-1_amd64.apk

RUN set -xe \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .persistent-deps freetds unixodbc \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps $PHPIZE_DEPS unixodbc-dev freetds-dev \
    && docker-php-source extract \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_dblib \
    && pecl install sqlsrv-5.6.1 pdo_sqlsrv-5.6.1 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable --ini-name 30-sqlsrv.ini sqlsrv \
    && docker-php-ext-enable --ini-name 35-pdo_sqlsrv.ini pdo_sqlsrv \
    && docker-php-source delete \
    && apk del .build-deps
```